# How to get pass FTM on my ZTE Android mobile device trying to turn on?

Tags: factory-reset, recovery-mode

My ZTE Android Edition by SFR, StarAddict is unable to turn on. I cannot get pass the Android logo. I have long pressed on Volume Down and Power buttons at the same time but it only ended me up at FTM. What next? Please help me reset or turn on my phone. The only external buttons on this phone are: Volume Up or Down, Power, Menu,Home and Back.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the volume up and power and when reboot screen comes up select reboot device by scrolling with the volume and then select with the power button

Answer (score 0):

I just had mine continuously restarting last night. It would not turn off no matter what I did. I finally had a lightbulb moment and I put my phone in the freezer. I left it there for 30 minutes and guess what, it finally restarted my phone and put it in regular mode. I was worried that my phone was broken as pressing the buttons had no effect.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these instructions:

1. Hold Power button and Volume Up button simultaneously until the phone vibrates and turns on.
2. Once the screen has turned on, you will have an option to select Recovery mode, Fastboot or Normal mode. Select Recovery mode using Volume Up button.
3. To enter the selected choice (Recovery mode), enter using Volume Down button.
4. You would receive an Android (No Command) image. You will need to rapidly click Volume Up button and Power button together a few times until you get past Android (No Command) image.
5. You will then be able to get into Boot loader, Recovery mode. Select Factory reset.